# Cache response body from http request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, caching

I am looking for a way to cache the response from a http get request and everytime the user opens the app i want to compare the data in the cache with the data from the request and display the http response instead of the cached data if there is any difference

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the package [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager), that should fit your needs.